# Communicating between two Raspberry Pi

Tags: communication

I would like to know what way can two Raspberry Pi communicate in? Here's the case, I am going do an autonomous robot called Micromouse with Raspberry. And I want them to run in one 16x16 maze in the same time and wont bump into each other.

Is there any communication way to let them avoid that? How?

Comment: In standard configuration you have USB and cabled Ethernet.  If you need anything else you need additional hardware.

Comment: Presuming the pi's are not moving at a significant % of Einstein's *c*, regular wifi through a router should be fine.  Especially if you put the router on a little platform in the middle of the maze, lol.

Comment: Using wifi with them would be a good idea - so that they do not bump into each other, you could mount infrared LEDs on one, and sensors on the other. Then when the one with the sensors detects the other's LEDs, it could work out the direction the other is in and go the other way. This is mostly theoretical, and is an idea more than anyhting. *(N.B. - If you got another set of Infrared LEDs and sensors - **but at a different wavelength** - you could do sensors and LEDs on both robots)*. If you are interested in this mad idea, look at electronics places like [Farnell](http://www.farnell.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You will need additional hardware if you don't want them physically wired together.

Your choices for the communication medium are:

- Ad-hoc WiFi connection
- Bluetooth
- Infra Red

All these are available in the market.  You need to do some homework and decide which is most appropriate for you.

Comment: [ZigBee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZigBee) is another option if you want low power over long distance.

Comment: @earthmeLon:  Good point.  I hadn't seen that available on the RPi.

Answer (score 1):

You can get NRF24L01+ modules very cheaply from a variety of websites. They have an SPI interface and some people have had success using them with raspberrypis

[image]